# This context lost and asyncResult.context undefined in OfficeJS method callbacks

Tags: typescript, office-js

I'm missing something obvious. 
Using Office.js with TypeScript, when attempting to execute the method supplied to the callback parameter of certain functions like `makeEwsRequestAsync(data, callback)` any local functions (or variables, for that matter) called within this `callback()` come back undefined, resulting in "`xyz Is not a function`" errors.

I assume this is due to `this` changing when executing in the context of the `makeEwsRequestAsync(data, callback)` function. How do I go about passing these functions or parameters explicitly, without `this`? Or am I incorrect in this assumption, and something else is causing this issue?

```
 sendRequest() {
   Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
     this.getSubjectRequest(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId), this.callback);
 }

 callback(asyncResult) {
   let result = asyncResult.value;

   //Result processing happens here

   // \/ This throws "PostFile is not a function"
   this.PostFile(base64String);
 }

 PostFile(base64String: string) {
   //POST happens here
 }
```

I also tried using the optional "userContext" parameter of `makeEwsRequestAsync` as follows:

```
outerThis: thisService

sendRequest(folderId: string) {
    this.folderId = folderId;

    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
      this.getSubjectRequest(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId), this.callback, this.outerThis);
  }
```

And then retrieving the context through `asyncResult.context` in the callback, but the context does not get populated as expected and returns `undefined`. In fact the only properties in the "asyncResult" object are "value" and "status" instead of "value" and "context".

Thanks in advance, any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I go about passing these functions or parameters explicitly, without this?

It's called binding what you are looking for, you can archive it in two ways:

With the .bind() method:

```
 sendRequest() {
   Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
     this.getSubjectRequest(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId), this.callback.bind(this));
 }
callback() {/*...*/}
```

or with help of an arrow function (bind automatically):

```
sendRequest() {
   Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
     this.getSubjectRequest(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId), this.callback);
 }
callback = (asyncResult) => {
   let result = asyncResult.value;

   //Result processing happens here

   // \/ This throws "PostFile is not a function"
   this.PostFile(base64String);
 }
```

or the very old way of doing it (not recommended):

```
const that = this
```

and then use `that` in the callback instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this was exactly what I was looking for here. Are there any situations where I should explicitly avoid using bind()? Only asking since I'd assume it would be called by default if this was not the case.

Comment: Only bind when necerssay, most of the time in callbacks for event handlers. Tip: read about `.bind()`, `.call()`, and `.apply()`, they do more or less the same thing and are very handy in some situations.